# Future web call storing data

Tags: apex, rest-api

Hello I have built a custom APEX class that allows us to reach out to Trello to create a new card based on your custom ticketing object.

Basically we are using multiple post and get future methods to work out the following:

**getTrelloBoard**

Basically loads all the boards that our org has

**getTrelloList**

Pulls the list that is related to the board above

**getTrelloLabels**

Pulls the labels related to the board

Basically as these are future methods I cannot return the values to the invocable method so need to maintain and update these values so they can be used in a custom flow.

What would people suggest (Custom Meta data types ?)

Open to any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

All I know from your post is that you are connecting to Trello somehow and manipulating data from that connection in your Salesforce org.

If you are trying to keep data around for later use after your future calls resolve, you may want to look at the platform cache feature in salesforce.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_cache_namespace_overview.htm

Hope that helps.